# One invoice to multiple customers in access

Tags: database, forms, ms-access-2010, relationship, ms-access-2007

I have so far 5 tables:

Customers (name, type of basket, frequency...)
Basket_junction (delivered, paid...)
Basket (year, week, odd or even, type of basket...)
Basket_details (product name, quantity...)
Products (name, price...)

(I didn't put on purpose the primary keys and numerous autonumbered IDs)

I would like to be able in a form to create a basket that can be applied to a list of customers depending on their type of basket (subscription) and frequency.

For example, I create on week S2 a P12 basket containing a certain amount of products in a form. And i want this basket attached to all of the customers who have the "P12" subscription on even weeks. I want then to be able to say for each customer if the basket has been delivered and paid.

I am pretty new to this.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. Are you looking to write a SQL query that determines which baskets have been delivered and paid?

Comment: I would like to create a query, or a form, for example, that can save for all P12 customers (for example) my P12 basket. And then, for all of those customers, i'll be able to say "delivered" or "paid" (but that i think i can manage). My issue so far is to mass save my P12 basket for all the P12 customers

Comment: This isn't my technology, but I wonder if people are seeing this (21 people) and finding it rather broad or lacking focus. Will readers know what a P12 basket is? I wonder if this is a basket of a type matching a string in Excel field P12? Similarly, is week S2 an Excel reference?

Comment: If you can do some research on how this might be done, you could decide on a direction and make an attempt to implement this. In general this will produce a much more concrete question, as you can then show people what you have tried.